# Outlook Error for users who upgraded to Outlook 2010 from 2003/2007 (PC)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

There are several users I support who have upgraded to Microsoft Outlook 2010 from Outlook 2003/2007 who receive this error, *"You are not responding to the latest message in this conversation"*, when reply to forwarded emails or emails with attachments.  Many people believe that this is an error with conversation view, however the users who are receiving this error do not use conversation view.  Ideas?

Comment: *Update- I have deleted the conversation history on the users computer and they were able to send mail for a day.  The problem has occurred again and Outlook will not send the messages.

Comment: How did you delete conversation history? We have this same issue? If you can tell me how then maybe I can use GP to keep it clean.